# How to use admin console when install glassfish-3.0 by extract from zip file?

Tags: installation, glassfish, automated-install

There are two types of glassfish distribution: the executable installer and zip archive.

I have to use the zip archive. But the admin console doesn't work, it only shows a blue footer div, the resource `/theme/META-INF/com_sun_faces_ajax.js` is not found and error in the page:

```
http://localhost:4848/:

...
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (true) {
        //submitAndDisable(document.getElementById('loginButton'), 'Login');
        document.getElementById('loginButton').form.submit();

        // ERROR HERE:
        //    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of null

    }
</script>
```

when installed by extract from zip archive, but it works very well if install by the executable installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran into the Javascript errors you're describing, it was because of an issue with OpenJDK and Glassfish, which I resolved by installing Sun Java. I don't know if that will make a difference in your situation.

Here's where I got the tip that it was an OpenJDK problem: http://explodingjava.blogspot.com/2010/05/oracle-sun-jdk-vs-openjdk-and-jsf.html

Comment: This is unbelievable. The Sun JDK really works!